# when i add a new field to database it's overwrite the last i added

Tags: database, forms, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a database using MS Access, but I have a problem

I create a form and I use that form to add the data to the table
the problem is when I add a new data row it overwrite the last I added 
Is there a way to solve this, so that I won't overwrite the previous added value?

another question how to show data only related for user log in such as personal information?

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: for the first question I solved it: view>design view>selection type: form>data entry: yes

Comment: I need the answer for the second question please